# Limit allowed types of attachment files to the few I need

Tags: attachment, swiftmailer

I got Swiftmailer today and it works fine for me, but it would be much better 
if O could change the allowed file types for attachments. I read the Documentation for Attachments a hundred times but I'm still unable to send a DXF or ZIP file via POST from a Webform. I use this code:

```
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['anhang']['tmp_name'])) {
    $message->attach(
    Swift_Attachment::fromPath($_FILES['anhang']['tmp_name'])->setFilename($_FILES['anhang']['name']) 
  );
}
```

to figure it out. Please help me to let the users of my form 
only send me JPG, PNG, ZIP, DXF, DWG and PDF files.

I'm also interested in hiding "hidden" form fields in the email (like maximum file size for POST Upload).

Comment: It possible to allow file types via post or depends this on swiftmail?

Comment: Well thanks for this amount of help.